# how to create an extension method with system namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have 2 class libraries (C#), Say **A** and **B**.

Library **`A`** has some methods in it. These methods need and an extension method to cipher/decipher their values.

Library **`B`** does this job. This library has an extension method but extending it in `System` namespace.

```
namespace System
{
    public static class EncryptDecrypt  
    {
        public static string ToEncrypt(this Object toEncrypt)
        {

        }

        public static string ToDecrypt(this string toDecrypt)
        {

        }
   }
}
```

The reason I had it in `System` namespace was to use this extension throughout all application without needing to import in `using` section.

**Please note**

Library **`B`** will always be used as `.dll` reference because it has a private key (a secret key) for cipher/decipher.
So wherever I will use this library; I would have a public key to get things encrypted.

I had setup it all and when I try it; It gives me compile time error for every extension wherever I am using it.

So If I am using it on a string `item.Member_FirstName.ToEncrypt()`

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToEncrypt' and no
>   extension method 'ToEncrypt' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

**But when I go to the definition of these extension methods. These are going on correct definition of theirs in Library **`B`**.**

I suspect there are conflicts with Library **`A's`** System namespace and **`B's`** System namespace?

Please correct me.

Comment: `using EncryptDecrypt`

Comment: @LeiYang, Dont need that actually as namespace is `System`. I pointed that out in question somewhere.

Comment: System is reserved for the Microsoft Net Library.  You don't have access to add items to this library.  So you should make any custom library use your own root namespace.

Comment: So, you're choosing to put it in system because *by default* most classes will already have a `using System;` at the top? That seems like poor reasoning. People *expect* to have to insert appropriate `using`s to bring extension methods into scope. Trying to "cheat" them in just seems like a poor idea.

Comment: @jdweng, If I do it within the same library then it works. I have all access to it.

Comment: This is a bad idea.

Comment: Does `A` have reference to `B`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, What is bad in it ? It is reducing expense of mandatory using section everywhere where I would use it.

Comment: i just had a test, within the same assembly, i can accomplish using extension methods `using System;`. so i just guess, it is because if both .net  's builtin library and your library are referenced, .net built in has a priority?

Comment: @Aniket, Yes I have referenced A with B

Comment: @Manoz - so, when Microsoft introduced LINQ and expected it to be used in lots of places, you think they were foolish to place all of the LINQ extension methods in a separate namespace. Effectively, you're *polluting* the namespace by making your extensions practically inescapable.

Comment: I gotta check this one then.

Comment: seems like security trespassing core libraries

Comment: Manoz can you upload a working "test" solution somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx

> Core namespaces include all System namespaces, excluding namespaces of
> the application models and the Infrastructure namespaces. Core
> namespaces include, among others, System, System.IO, System.Xml, and
> System.Net.
>
> X DO NOT give types names that would conflict with any
> type in the Core namespaces.

The caps are all there's I think they really really don't want you to do this.  Why ? Because how would anyone be able to trust the .NET framework if there were 3rd party assemblies flying round, throwing in their own methods and classes in among the namespaces for the core framework ?